# How change default props of the component event in React-big-calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to use React-big-calendar

Concerning the default component event, it contains these following details:
start time,
end time,
title,
whether its an "all day" event or not,
any resource the event may be a related too

I need to add 3 others details in this component, how can I do?
I saw that I can customize the style of the component but I don't know how to add props.
I hope my question is clear, I'm new in developpment and it's the first time I post here.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Any props that you add to your 'event' (that is, the object describing an 'event' that is part of your `events` array prop) are available to your custom event in it's `event` prop. For instance, my custom event layout looks something like this:

```js
const StandardEvent = ({ event }) => {
  const { timezone } = useAppointments();
  return (
    <div className={styles.customEventLayout}>
      <div className={styles.eventTitle}>
        {event.PatientFamilyName && event.PatientGivenName && (
          <Fragment>
            <StatusIndicator event={event} />
            <span className="text-strong">
              {event.PatientFamilyName}, {event.PatientGivenName}
            </span>
            <br />
          </Fragment>
        )}
        <span
          className={classnames({
            'text-strong': !event.PatientFamilyName && !event.PatientGivenName,
          })}
        >
          {event.EncounterTypeDescription}
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.eventDate}>
        {moment.tz(event.StartDateTime, timezone).format('hh:mm a')}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can tell a little from the code, my 'event' structure (from the db, and just prior to date conversions before dropping into my `events` prop) looks a little like:

```json
{
  "StartDateTime": "2021-11-07T08:15:00Z",
  "EndDateTime": "2021-11-07T08:30:00Z",
  "PatientGivenName": "Robert",
  "PatientFamilyName": "Plant",
  "EncountTypeDescription": "Annual Physical",
  "IsAllDayAppointment": false
}
```

Comment: thanks for your explainations Steve-Cutter-Blades!